# Ajax not transmiting the correct parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax request but the parameter I want to send is not transmited ok. So I have 
user.php

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {

  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  document.write(str);
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">John Smith</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This seems to retrieve the value correctly. If I select `Joseph Swanson` there is a `3` displayed which is ok. But when I go to `getUser.php`

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
var_dump($q);
?>
```

I get `int 0` every time.
What is the problem?

Comment: try `$q = $_GET['q']; echo $q;`

Comment: it'll work just fine if paired with your xmlhttprequest, the problem is that you're trying to access the page normally (`getUser.php` only) thus that being undefined. http://codepad.viper-7.com/a7eRcw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value is numeric before assigning as intval. Here is from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

> Return Values
>
> The integer value of var on success, or 0 on failure. Empty arrays
>   return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.
>
> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum
>   signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on
>   such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The
>   maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is
>   9223372036854775807.
>
> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting
>   apply.

I would recommend using JQuery instead for AJAX, much easier to grasp when you are learning.

```
//add JQuery//
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getuser.php", //assumes file is in root dir//
            type: "post",
            data: "q="+str,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                alert ("processed"); //alerts that PHP processed the request//
                $("#txtHint").html(response); //inserts echoed data into div//
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Then in the PHP file, try adding...

```
echo $_POST['q'];
exit;
```

This will at least tell you that they are talking. But it won't be visible on the screen, you'll need to look in developer tools -> network -> response (but should also be in `#txtHint`). If you get a response remove that and try normally.

**EDIT :**
Also check the network tab in the developer tools for the request to make sure that it is being sent.

Comment: If I do it your way I get `null` . I really don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: More than likely the variable is empty, I will revise my answer.

Comment: Well now I get `string 'empty' (length=5)` Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: is strange that I get `Undefined index: q` on this line `if (is_numeric($_GET['q'])) {`

Comment: Either the value is not being assigned properly in your javascript or maybe the `$_GET` request is not being received by PHP. Maybe try taking out `document.write(str);`.

Comment: isn't there another way to go to `getUser.php`? Maybe by using `post`?

Comment: I will accept the answer for the time spent and all the solutions proposed, but it hasn't yet fixed my problem

Comment: Do you see it sending in the network tab of the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: Yes, i get a `status ok`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70024/discussion-between-eternalhour-and-dres).

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when there is nothing like `q` in the query string at time when you are accessing the page norally. Add -

```
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
  $q = intval($_GET['q']);
  var_dump($q);
}
```

Now it will display only when it gets the parameter in the url.

Comment: I changed that and I get `Undefined variable: q`

Comment: You might be using `$q` somewhere else on that page.Add the check, it will be fixed.